# Can I use windows flutter sdk in ubuntu?

Tags: flutter

I need to run the flutter project in ubuntu, also I need to run the project in three different flutter SDK versions. So I use the flutter SDK management tool [`fvm`](https://github.com/leoafarias/fvm) to switch version. When I use `fvm install <version>` in ubuntu, it's so slow. So I come up that because I have finished the same work in Windows 10, so can I copy the three versions of flutter SDK in windows 10 into my Ubuntu? I have searched on flutter official website they do distinguish different versions for different OS, I'm not sure if they are the same.

Answer (score 1):

When installing Flutter, some platform-specific binaries are downloaded, so no, they aren't the same.

Comment: OK, thanks for your answer. So, can I download and replace some certain files to make it suitable?

Comment: By platform, I mean windows vs unix vs mac.  All linux versions for x86 are essentially the same Flutter distro, as are all ARM versions of linux. Platform = "OS family" + "processor instruction set".